# Execute multiple owl carousel on one page with php

Tags: php, owl-carousel

I have an OWL carousel in one section which pulls images with this PHP code.

```
<?php $count = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
  the_widget( 'post_widget1', 'count='.$count.'&orderby=date' );
?>
```

I am trying to display another carousel using exactly the same code again but with a little different settings set in post_widget2 so currently my code looks like:

```
<section class="vbox">
<section class="scrollable padder-lg">

<h4>New</h4><hr />

<?php 
$count = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
the_widget( 'post_widget1', 'count='.$count.'&orderby=name' );
?>

</section>
</section>


<section class="vbox">
<section class="scrollable padder-lg">

<h4>New</h4><hr />

<?php 
$count = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
the_widget( 'post_widget2', 'count='.$count.'&orderby=date' );
?>

</section>
</section>



<script src="owl-carousel/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  var owl = $("#owl-demo");
  var owl = $("#owl-demo2");


  owl.owlCarousel({

  items : 5, //10 items above 1000px browser width
  navigation : false,
  pagination : false,
  responsive : true,
  autoPlay : true,
  navigationText : ["<",">"]
  });

  $(".next").click(function(){
  owl.trigger('owl.next');
  })
  $(".prev").click(function(){
  owl.trigger('owl.prev');
})

});
</script>
```

The carousel will only display once. I realised it is because the php script is only executed once, my question is how can I get it to work twice on the same page?

Comment: I think you just want to do this: `var owl = $("#owl-demo,#owl-demo2");`, because now you overwrite the `owl` var, and therefor it is only triggered for demo 2 and not demo, by combining the selector you can trigger the owlCarousel to work for both.

Comment: Thanks, I am a bit of a novice so the obvious isn't so obvious to me sometimes :P I have amended that part of the script but it still only shows the first carousel.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like your problem is with the javascript not the PHP:

```
var owl = $("#owl-demo");
var owl = $("#owl-demo2");
```

You're using the same variable name, so it just overwrites the first one.

Comment: I have amended that part of the script using Bas van Stein's suggestion but it still only shows the first carousel.